# Javascript prototypal inheritance weirdness

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to work through some javascript inheritance examples and I hit a wall with this one:

```
function Animal(){}
Animal.prototype.type = "animal";
Animal.prototype.speak = function(){ console.log( "I'm a " + this.type + 
    ". I can't really talk ;)" ); }

function Dog(){}

function F(){}
F.prototype = Animal.prototype;

Dog.prototype = new F();
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.type = "Dog";
Dog._super = Animal.prototype;
Dog.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); _super.speak(); }

var rover = new Dog();
rover.woof();
```

I am getting this and I have no idea why:

```
TypeError: Object #<Dog> has no method 'woof'
```

I know I can put the not-found method into the constructor function, but I am trying to do this with prototype modification. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `woof` should be under prototype of dog to be invoked as `Dog.woof()`

Comment: @Deeptechtons can you submit your suggestion as a succinct answer? I'm not following 100%.

Comment: my answer would be more or less the same as bjornd's

Comment: @javamonkey79 - objects inherit from their constructor's prototype, not the constructor itself. So *rover* inherits from *Dog.prototype*, not *Dog*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
Dog._super = Animal.prototype;
Dog.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); _super.speak(); }
```

To:

```
// Dog.prototype._super = Animal.prototype; <- you can remove this line
Dog.prototype.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); this.speak(); }
```

Comment: Ah, I think I see my mistake now. Ug - I was trying to add the function to the Dog function, which is a function object, not a Dog object. Man alive grokking prototype inheritance is tricky! Thanks.

Comment: @javamonkey79 I made a correction to my answer; it now logs `I'm a Dog, I can't really talk` instead of `I'm a Animal, I can't really talk`

Comment: oh, cool - I think either solution is fine...I had the "ah ha" moment of what I was doing wrong. Thank God for SO :)

Comment: @javamonkey79 Oh, you can remove the reference to `_super` unless you need it for some other reason. You don't really need here.

Answer (score 4):

The last string of the Dog pseudo-class definition is wrong. It should be

```
Dog.prototype.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); Dog._super.speak.call(this); }
```

1. You should define method `woof` as the property of the `Dog`'s prototype.
2. `_super` is available only as the property of the `Dog` constructor.
3. You should call the methods of the parent class in context of the current instance.

Comment: +1 For making it work correctly and making me realize I had a mistake in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

So your woof method is actually effectively a static method (If you're coming from java. Basically, it's hanging off the Dog function, and can be accessed without an instance of Dog. ie: Dog.woof())

To get it working with an instance of a dog, you want to make sure it's a prototype definition (again, with a Java analogy, effectively a instance method definition). As qwertymik said,

```
Dog.prototype.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); this.speak(); }
```

Then you'll be able to do

```
var foo = new Dog();
foo.woof();
```

Comment: right, I think I thought about this when I had my "ah ha" moment due to @NullUserExceptions answer, however, this is good that you bring it up for others +1 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean to do this:

```
Dog.prototype._super = Animal.prototype;
Dog.prototype.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); this._super.speak(); }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work. I am using node.js standalone exe.

Comment: It would work if woof was defined as `function() { ...; this._super.speak.call(this())}`. As is, the context of the `speak` call will be `Animal.prototype` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Rewrote the code to make it work

function Animal(){}
Animal.prototype.type = "animal";
Animal.prototype.speak = function(){ console.log( "I'm a " + this.type + 
    ". I can't really talk ;)" ); }

function Dog(){}
function F(){}

F.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); //F inherits from animal
Dog.prototype = Object.create(F.prototype);    //Dog inherits from F

Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog; //resetting the constructor to Dog object
F.prototype.constructor=F;       // resetting the constrctor to F object 

Dog.prototype.type = "Dog";

Dog.prototype.woof = function(){ console.log( "Woof!" ); this.speak(); } //adding woof method to the prototype of dog

const rover = new Dog();

rover.woof();

// output
// Woof!
// I'm a Dog. I can't really talk ;)
```